# Dividing turtles with percentages and assign values according to their groups

Tags: netlogo, agent-based-modeling

I have a set of agents represented by turtles. I need to divide the turtles in group according to certain percentages. Then, I need to assign values for a turtle-owned variable (X) against the respective groups. Following is the code I developed -

```
ask n-of (count turtles * 0.50) turtles [
    set X  5.04]
if X != 5.04 [
  ask n-of (count turtles * 0.25) turtles [
    set X  26.2]
    ]
if X != 5.04 or X != 26.2 [
    ask n-of (count turtles * 0.25) turtles [
    set X  58]
    ]
```

But, after implementing this code I see the number of turtles with the assigned values are nor accurate. For example, I have 200 turtles. But, the number of turtles that got X=5.04 is not 100 (50%).

Comment: Please edit your question instead of posting an answer which contains an update to your question

Comment: You changed the question too much. You cannot completely rewrite it to ask something else. You cannot invalidate answers with your edit. If you have a new question then post a new question entirely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is you are not referring to turtles with the `X` variable with the value you already set. That should be done with something like:

```
ask turtles with [X != 5.04] [
  set X 26.2
]
```

However, as when a variable is defined its default initial value is 0, I usually do this kind of distribution like this, which I think it is cleaner and easier to work with:

```
ask n-of (round (0.50 * count turtles)) turtles with [X = 0] [set X 5.04]
ask n-of (round (0.25 * count turtles)) turtles with [X = 0] [set X 26.2]
ask n-of (round (0.25 * count turtles)) turtles with [X = 0] [set X   58]
ask turtles with [X = 0] [set X one-of [5.04 26.2 58]]
```

If you are creating just 200 turtles, `round` and the last line won't be necessary. But those are useful when you are dealing with more complicated percentages or uneven groups of turtles.

Comment: I got my mistake. The suggestions you gave me is working accurately for me now. My mistake was putting 'ask n-of (.....) turtles' within the 'ask turtles [....]' command. In this way, I commanded turtles to repeat the same thing, thus the percentage rules  did not get sufficient number of agents.

Comment: Yes, when you use, ```ask n-of X turtles``` the chosen set is completely random. It is necessary to make sure you are excluding the turtles you already modified as you wanted to by adding the ```with [ ]```, so you prevent them of changing their variable value again.